# Python XLWT: Excel generated by Python xlwt contains missing value

Tags: python, xlwt

I'm quite new to Python and trying to fetch data in HTML and saved to excels using xlwt.

So far the program seems work well (all the output are correctly printed on the python console when running the program) except that when I open the excel file, an error message saying *'We found a problem with some content in FILENAME, Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.'* And after I click Yes, I found that a lot of data fields are missing.

It seems that roughly the first 150 lines are fine and the problem begins to rise after that (In total around 15000 lines). And missing data fields concentrate at several columns with relative high data volume.

I'm thinking if it's related to sort of cache allocating mechanism of xlwt?

Thanks a lot for your help here.

Answer (score -2):

seems like a caching issue.
Try sheet.flush_row_data() every 100 rows or so ?